# Multiple Cart or Split Quote in Magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, magento-2.1, quote

I want to show two cart for normal products and vendor products.

I don't think it possible to create **multiple cart** either by splitting quote or creating **multiple quote**.

Because Magento 2 separate module for Quote. Can anyone tell me how can i achieve my requirement?

thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this

Comment: did you find any solution.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Magento doesn't have UI for multiple quotes. Also, Magento relies on is_active quote field in order to bind the consumer to exactly one quote. However, you can use `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface` to introduce more active quotes per consumer. You also need to create custom UI for your custom quotes.

Comment: did you find any solution.